# How to get access token from Instagram API

Tags: swift, instagram-api

I've been following Instagram's basic guides here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions

I added my personal Instagram account as a tester and I got the authorization code, but when I send the request to get the access token, this is my response:

```
{
    "error_type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "Missing required field client_id"
}
```

This is my input in POSTMAN:

[image]

Any help or possible tips will greatly be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to me the error message is pretty clear. It says **Missing required field client_id**, and the input you're providing does not include a value for **client_id**.

Comment: I don't include it in the screenshot here bc i don't want to share my client id on stackoverflow @KenWhite hence the black box

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution to my own question here [Impossible to get an access_token for Instagram Basic Display API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58489682/impossible-to-get-an-access-token-for-instagram-basic-display-api?rq=1)

When using Postman for Instagram's API, you should fill out the info required under the POST request's *Body*, **NOT** the *Parameters*. And when in the body, just select *x-www-form-irlencoded*

Comment: Your a life saver mate

Comment: happy to help @Vikranth !

Comment: I put it in Body and it still says "Missing required field client_id". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification, you also have to keep "#_ at the end of the code for it to work (contrary to what the doc says)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31970220)

Answer (score 0):

rather than encoding the body - can use this approach for python.

```
import urllib3

def make_post_request(url, fields):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    response = http.request(
        'POST',
        url,
        fields=fields
    )
    return response.data.decode('utf-8')

url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
fields = {
    'client_id': '1234',
    'client_secret': 'ad09c61ac39488fc446b4bc0f05fddc9',
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': 'https://www.blabla.app/auth/',
    'code': '1234'
}

response = make_post_request(url, fields)
print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instagram redirects to your REDIRECT_URI, with the code in query params, but as I noticed there is missing **`#_`** at the end of the code string, which is present on instagram page after allow user permissions, add it to your retrieved code at the end if missing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35302300)