# Send data in body via POST - Flask

Tags: python, python-requests, instagram-api

I need to send a POST request to the Instagram Basic API with Flask.

This is my code:

```py
def get_token_insta(code):
    dict_to_send = {"client_id": "XXX",
                    "client_secret": "XXX",
                    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
                    "redirect_uri": "XXX",
                    "code": "XXX"}
    json_string = json.dumps(dict_to_send)
    res = requests.post('https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', data=json_string)
    data = res.json()
    print(data)
    # More code...
```

The code works fine, but the response from Instagram is

> { "error_type": "OAuthException", "code": 400, "error_message": "Missing required field client_id" }

Reading the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started) and this @murp [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467351/how-to-get-access-token-from-instagram-api) I need to put data inside the body of the POST request.

Am I wrong? How can I make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you find that you need to serialize POST *request parameters* to `json`? You'll get JSON response, sure, but you don't need to serialize request parameters.
Try just to pass `dict_to_send` itself as `data` parameter:

```py
requests.post(url, ..., data=dict_to_send)
```

more info in [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was thinking JSON was required